# Is it okay to use stainless steel in oven?

Tags: baking, equipment, oven, temperature

[image]

Its stainless steel dish so can I put it in the oven at 250c/482f ?

Comment: What is this pan meant for? Does it have a handle? If so, is the handle likely to be oven-safe? I have cookie sheets made out of stainless steel, and they (obviously) work just fine in the oven, so I wouldn't be overly concerned about the metal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask "can I put it in the oven?" you're actually not asking a whole question. Can you put it in the oven? Of course you can. Will anything happen to it and your food that you don't like? Ah, that is the other half, right? What might happen?

- the pan might warp (if it is thin)
- the food might scorch or burn (again, more likely if the pan is thin)
- the pan might stain (especially if there are areas of it that have only oil on them - for example if you're roasting a piece of meat)
- the food might stick to the pan and not come out well

If the pan is thick, and not a lot of it will be empty and exposed, then it should be fine. Another thing to consider is how you're going to get it out again after cooking. I don't see any handles.

Comment: If the dish is not meant for oven-safety, could it have a coating on it that will be affected by the high-heat of the oven?

Comment: that seems unlikely. A non-stick pan, sure. but a stainless steel pan, I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are cooking something in it. That's a pretty high temp and your stainless is going to get stained.

Comment: This answer seems a little too brief. Are you saying that 480F is hot enough to damage the stainless steel and that baking food in it would prevent this? (I presume moist food/steam keeping the temps down?)

Comment: Sort of...having food in the dish will keep its temp lower...however at that heat, the stainless is likely to develop a brown stain you can't get rid of.